# Can you get multiple right returns ELIF?

Tags: python

I was testing some code and a question popped up. For example; if you can select some multiple ingredients that returns you a smoothie receipt. But I want to have multiple right returns. Now I only get one. But if you have 1,3,4,8 in your fridge you can make two smoothies. But how do i tell Python?

```
Strawberry_boost = [1,6,3]
Hawaian_banana = [1,8,3]
Banana_splash = [1,3,4,8]


def showData():
   if (var1.get() == 1) and (var6.get() == 6) and (var3.get() == 3) in Strawberry_boost:
      label2 = Label(root, text = "                          Strawberry Boost                           ",bg='yellow')
      label2.grid(row=8,column=0)
   elif (var1.get() == 1) and (var3.get() == 3) and (var4.get() == 4) and (var8.get() == 8) in Banana_splash:
      label2 = Label(root, text = "                          Banana splash                          ",bg='yellow')
      label2.grid(row=8,column=0)
   elif  (var1.get() == 1) and (var8.get() == 8) and (var3.get() == 3) in Hawaian_banana:
      label2 = Label(root, text = "                          Hawaiian Banana                         ",bg='yellow') 
      label2.grid(row=8,column=0)
   else:
      label2 = Label(root, text = "            error       ",bg='yellow')
      label2.grid(row=8,column=0)
```

Note: the code is longer, but this is the part i struggle with

Comment: The very purpose of `elif` is to only run if no condition before it was true. If you want each check to be independent, just use separate `if`s.

Comment: Apart from what you are asking for, you are going to have problems with this code. The result from `(varX.get == X)` is either `True` or `False` and then you are `and`ing these values, which results in either `True` or `False`. So you are effectively asking if 0 or 1 is present in the lists you prepared.